# Disable warning C4251: "... needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class ..."

Tags: c++, templates, dll, stl, compiler-warnings

I am trying to workaround warning C4251: "... needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class ..." for STL classes in a less brutal way than wrapping every my class that uses STL with `#pragma warning( push )` and `#pragma warning( disable : 4251 )`, then `#pragma warning( pop )`.

So to achieve that, I try to export whatever I can from STL templates like the code below. However, there are some private nested STL classes which I can't export this way. So I still have to wrap the blocks of export of public STL classes into warning-disabling code:

```
#ifdef SRPLATFORM_EXPORTS
#define SRPLATFORM_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SRPLATFORM_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // SRPLATFORM_EXPORTS

#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4251 ) // needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class
class SRPLATFORM_API std::exception_ptr;
template struct SRPLATFORM_API std::atomic<int32_t>;
class SRPLATFORM_API std::thread;
template SRPLATFORM_API class std::allocator<std::thread>;
template class SRPLATFORM_API std::vector<std::thread>; // this is line 19 in my file
#pragma warning( pop )
```

However, I am still getting C4251 for the nested private STL classes:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\vector(701): warning C4251: 'std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>>::_Mypair': class 'std::_Compressed_pair<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::thread>>,std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::thread>>,true>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<_Ty,_Alloc>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::thread,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::thread>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\vector(680): note: see declaration of 'std::_Compressed_pair<std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::thread>>,std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::thread>>,true>'
1>d:\dev\views\engines\probqa\srplatform\../SRPlatform/Interface/SRPlatform.h(19): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::thread,std::allocator<std::thread>>' being compiled
```

So do I have to wrap in warning-disabling statements the include statements (like `#include <vector>`)? Or else, could someone clarify what's going on?

Comment: The warning comes from the template export statement `template class SRPLATFORM_API std::vector<std::thread>;`, long before the DLL-exported class that has `vector<thread>` as a member variable. And for performance reasons I'm going to leave it as a member variable anyway, because e.g. pImpl idiom would use heap-allocation rather than stack-allocation available if I declare that exported class as an object (local variable) in some function of the client/EXE .

Comment: I'd guess the warning comes from use of additional types used in the interface of `vector`, in the particular message it seems to be `std::pair` - if not exported, it could technically have different implementations in the DLL and in the client, therefore the warning. To get rid of the warnings, I guess you would need to export the additional types used in the vector interface as well.

Comment: It is the template constructor in std::thread that causes this warning.  Templates are never not a problem.  Hard to suppress, the linker errors are nasty so the compiler is assertive.  You could lie about it and add `class __declspec(dllimport) std::thread;` to your header.

Comment: @HansPassant, it's already there `class SRPLATFORM_API std::thread;`

Comment: Well, no, it needs to be dllimport so it is always active.  Post better repro code if that doesn't help.

Comment: @HansPassant, if it will be `dllimport` everywhere, then how will the solution compile/link without exporting this type from anywhere?

Comment: std::thread is completely defined in the header file, the linker never needs to find it.